# How to resolve data by ID from another index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having 2 indexes: `images` and `gallery`. `gallery` has only IDs of the images. Is there a way in Elasticsearch to return/resolve that data in the response? Or do I need to do 2 queries and resolve them on my own?

```
// image
{ id: 1, url: 'foo.bar' }
{ id: 2, url: 'foo.bar' }

// gallery
[1,2]

// result should be
[{ id: 1, url: 'foo.bar' }, { id: 2, url: 'foo.bar' }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Elasticsearch documentation on joining queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html), but both the options are for the same index, Elasticsearch doesn't offer the sql like JOIN operation as its costly and against the design of distributed system.

Even if you choose one of the option mentioned in the documentation, it's going to be costly than normal queries, I would suggest following.

1. If you have very less data `gallary` index, just the ids, then making second query isn't that costly, and in this case you don't have to change anything.
2. If performance is your concern, you can choose one of the option and compare the performance with first option with few tests, and whichever works  best for you, you can choose that. You can use the [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API to reindex the data in same index with required mapping.

Comment: The problem is that I already have the client side architecture which is built around 1 query.

Comment: @wintercounter, I am afraid than you don't have any other option apart from second query but it shouldn't be that much concerning as you have just ids in seconds index